# Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401)

Tags: chef-infra, apache-zookeeper, mesos, stratio

I have error on slave computers while setting up stratio manager.

```
Chef-client pid: 4846
Client key /etc/chef/client.pem is not present - registering
HTTP Request Returned 401 Unauthorized: error
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client)
Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401)
```

I can't find solution

Comment: Is the validation key present on the node?

Comment: what is validation key and how can I find it? or check if it's present on the node?

Comment: Google? https://docs.chef.io/chef_private_keys.html#chef-validator. Yes, make sure it's present (or if you explicitly bootstrap the node, you can use [validatorless bootstrap](https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/04/16/validatorless-bootstraps/)).

Comment: thanks for this link https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/04/16/validatorless-bootstraps/

Answer (score 1):

Generally this means that the client or node object already exists on the server. It can also be related to incorrect permissions on the validator key, but use of validator keys is no longer recommended to start with.

Comment: Yes permissions were incorrect. That was the problem :) thanks